# How to label events chronologically from most recent?

Tags: terminology

I'm working on a job application and would like to label the applicant's employment history starting with the most recent.

The most recent would obviously be labelled *Most Recent*. But how would I refer to the most recent after that? Next Most Recent? Second Most Recent?

Comment: Generally I see "Most Recent" and then "Previous", where everything in previous is sorted by date.  It's general practice to list dates of employment anyway, in which case the label would be superfluous.

Comment: @JohnFeltz - That's not a bad idea. If no one answers with anything that explicity refers to the next most recent, I will use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a long time since I asked the question but I ended up using "**Previous**" as suggested by @JohnFeltz in the comments.

It worked well given that its placement right after the most recent job indicated that I was looking for the job before that - or the **previous** job.

Answer (score 5):

A formal term used in such situations is ***reverse chronological order***.

money-zine.com:

> **Reverse Chronological Order** [Definition](http://www.money-zine.com/definitions/career-dictionary/reverse-chronological-order/)
>   The term reverse chronological order refers to a format that is commonly used in
>   combination resumes and chronological resumes to display work
>   experience or work history.  The reverse chronological order format
>   calls for the most recent work experience to appear first in the
>   document, while the oldest experience appears last.

You can set the context (perhaps an *always visible* heading) as "**In Reverse Chronological Order**" and number the history items starting at 1.

If explicit labeling of each item is desired, they can still be numbered (and annotated) like:

> First (in reverse chronological order) *aka* most recent
>   Second (in
>   reverse chronological order)
>   Third (in reverse chronological order)
>   ...

Comment: If I were giving directions, I could say "Add your employment history in reverse chronological order" but my question is asking for a way to label each one. Your answer isn't helpful for that.

Comment: Edited my answer to add the context of explicitly labeling history items. HTH.